# How are old cookies affected by the new Chrome SameSite changes?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I have many cookies that are used in a third-party context. I recently updated how we set cookies to be `SameSite` compliant. However, I still have many older cookies out there that were set prior to this change meaning they don't have a `SameSite` attribute explicitly set. When the `SameSite` changes all roll out, will I still be able to access those old cookies?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing cookies without a `SameSite` attribute will have the default behaviour of `SameSite=Lax` applied to them, meaning they will be restricted to same-site or first-party contexts only. If you only need cookies on your site, e.g. sessions, local CSRF tokens, preferences, etc. then this is most likely fine - though it's good practice to explicitly set `SameSite`.

If you need those cookies in any kind of cross-site or third-party context, e.g. embedded in an `iframe`, an `img`, a `fetch()`, etc. from a different site then you definitely do need to add `SameSite=None; Secure` or those existing cookies will not be included on those cross-site requests.

More information is available on:

- https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained
- https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! Sounds like existing third-party cookies without `SameSite` will just be lost.

Comment: To be precise, those cookies *are still there* in the browser, they are just treated as if they had `SameSite=Lax` specified. Meaning, they will still be sent in first-party contexts. So, if you need them in a third-party context, you should be sending an updated `Set-Cookie` or `document.cookie` assignment with `SameSite=None; Secure`.